Why does shopify api ask for authentication when uploading file?
I'm trying to upload a file to Shopify API.
I takes two steps:

Request a temporary upload folder at https://shopify-staged-uploads.storage.googleapis.com
Upload the file

The first step works fine, and I get all the parameters I need, but when I'm trying to upload the file I get this error:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>MissingSecurityHeader</Code><Message>Your request was missing a required header.</Message><Details>Authorization</Details></Error>

Accouring to the documentation (https://shopify.dev/docs/api/usage/bulk-operations/imports) no Authorization header is needed.
Here is the example curl from the documentation, and i uses no Authorization header. So why am I asked for that header?
curl --location --request POST 'https://shopify-staged-uploads.storage.googleapis.com/' \
--form 'key="tmp/21759409/bulk/2d278b12-d153-4667-a05c-a5d8181623de/bulk_op_vars"' \
--form 'x-goog-credential="merchant-assets@shopify-tiers.iam.gserviceaccount.com/20220830/auto/storage/goog4_request"' \
--form 'x-goog-algorithm="GOOG4-RSA-SHA256"' \
--form 'x-goog-date="20220830T025127Z"' \
--form 'x-goog-signature="************"' \
--form 'policy="***************"' \
--form 'acl="private"' \
--form 'Content-Type="text/jsonl"' \
--form 'success_action_status="201"' \
--form 'file=@"/Users/username/Documents/bulk_mutation_tests/products_long.jsonl"'

The content of the file I'm trying to upload is this:
{ "input": { "title": "Sweet new snowboard 1", "productType": "Snowboard", "vendor": "JadedPixel" } }
{ "input": { "title": "Sweet new snowboard 2", "productType": "Snowboard", "vendor": "JadedPixel" } }
{ "input": { "title": "Sweet new snowboard 3", "productType": "Snowboard", "vendor": "JadedPixel" } }

Here is my code:
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using ShopifyBulkUploadPoc;

var client = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://xxx.myshopify.com/admin/api/2021-07/graphql.json");
request.Headers.Add("X-Shopify-Access-Token", "xxx");
request.Headers.Add("Cookie", "_master_udr=xxx; _shopify_y=xxx; localization=DK; secure_customer_sig=");
var content = new StringContent("{\"query\":\"mutation {\\r\\n  stagedUploadsCreate(input:{\\r\\n    resource: BULK_MUTATION_VARIABLES,\\r\\n    filename: \\\"bulk_op_vars\\\",\\r\\n    mimeType: \\\"text/jsonl\\\",\\r\\n    httpMethod: POST\\r\\n  }){\\r\\n    userErrors{\\r\\n      field,\\r\\n      message\\r\\n    },\\r\\n    stagedTargets{\\r\\n      url,\\r\\n      resourceUrl,\\r\\n      parameters {\\r\\n        name,\\r\\n        value\\r\\n      }\\r\\n    }\\r\\n  }\\r\\n}\",\"variables\":{}}", null, "application/json");
request.Content = content;
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

Rootobject rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(responseContent);

var url = rootObject.data.stagedUploadsCreate.stagedTargets[0].url;
var key = rootObject.data.stagedUploadsCreate.stagedTargets[0].parameters[3].value;
var acl = rootObject.data.stagedUploadsCreate.stagedTargets[0].parameters[2].value;
var x_goog_date = rootObject.data.stagedUploadsCreate.stagedTargets[0].parameters[4].value;
var x_goog_credential = rootObject.data.stagedUploadsCreate.stagedTargets[0].parameters[5].value;
var x_goog_algorithm = rootObject.data.stagedUploadsCreate.stagedTargets[0].parameters[6].value;
var x_goog_signature = rootObject.data.stagedUploadsCreate.stagedTargets[0].parameters[7].value;
var policy = rootObject.data.stagedUploadsCreate.stagedTargets[0].parameters[8].value;
var content_type = rootObject.data.stagedUploadsCreate.stagedTargets[0].parameters[0].value;
var success_action_status = rootObject.data.stagedUploadsCreate.stagedTargets[0].parameters[1].value;

var requestB = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, "https://shopify-staged-uploads.storage.googleapis.com/");
var contentB = new MultipartFormDataContent();

contentB.Add(new StringContent(key), "key");
contentB.Add(new StringContent(x_goog_credential), "x-goog-credential");
contentB.Add(new StringContent(x_goog_algorithm), "x-goog-algorithm");
contentB.Add(new StringContent(x_goog_date), "x-goog-date");
contentB.Add(new StringContent(x_goog_signature), "x-goog-signature");
contentB.Add(new StringContent(policy), "policy");
contentB.Add(new StringContent(acl), "acl");
contentB.Add(new StringContent(content_type), "Content-Type");
contentB.Add(new StringContent(success_action_status), "success_action_status");

contentB.Add(new StreamContent(File.OpenRead("C:/products.jsonl")), "file", "/C:/products.jsonl");

requestB.Content = content;

var responseB = await client.SendAsync(requestB);
Console.WriteLine(await responseB.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

namespace ShopifyBulkUploadPoc
{
    public class Rootobject
    {
        public Data data { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public Stageduploadscreate stagedUploadsCreate { get; set; }
    }

    public class Stageduploadscreate
    {
        public object[] userErrors { get; set; }
        public Stagedtarget[] stagedTargets { get; set; }
    }

    public class Stagedtarget
    {
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string resourceUrl { get; set; }
        public Parameter[] parameters { get; set; }
    }

    public class Parameter
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }
}


Can you compare the actual request from your code to the curl request and look for any differences?

I get the same error running the CURL command
